# Getting error "Invalid Credentials" while using youtube v3 api

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to load my youtube account private video in my website. For this i am using V3 Data Api. I have tried with example provided in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php with video_localization.php. After a long struggle i got a form to enter video id and all. After submission ended with the following error message.

A service error occurred: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }

Please help me to work around this.

Looking forward for your reply.

Thanks,

Amar

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your credentials are invalid, check your credentials.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#UNAUTHORIZED) about this error says:

> **`authError`**:
>
> The authorization credentials provided for the request are invalid.
>   Check the value of the **`Authorization`** HTTP request header.